# Is it correct to use a full URI as a parameter to another operation?

Tags: rest

Is it correct to use a full URI as a parameter to another operation?

I think this is best described by example:

Consumer calls: http://my-rest.my-org.com/api/films

And receives a film

- Name: Reservoir Dogs
- DirectorName: Quentin Tarantino
- DirectorId: 1237
- Director: http://my-rest.my-org.com/api/directors/Quentin%20Tarantino

It makes sense to give out the URI for the director so that the consumer can go and fetch that data

Here's the part that doesn't seem right to me...

There is some *other* operation, a search, for example, that does not return a single type of resource and needs a few parameters to function; therefor it has no **fixed** set of URI's (perhaps the data behind it very dynamic)

For example a search function constrained by director: GET/ search-by-director?director={0}&keyword={1}&foo={2}&bar={3}

Now the question, is it okay? Is it sane? to have an operation that takes the full URI as one of the operation's parameters? Resulting in:

http://my-rest.my-org.com/api/search-by-director?director=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-rest.my-org.com%2Fapi%2Fdirectors%2FQuentin%2520Tarantino&Term=Mr%Pink

My natural inclination is that the Search, constrained by director operation, should use the DirectorId (Or better, a director Alias that is a human readable, unique representation of the director name).

http://my-rest.my-org.com/api/search-by-director?director=1237&Term=Mr%Pink

There are obviously ways to refactor this to get the parameters as "slash" URI segments which would make it look nicer (although even more horrific with the encoded URI for the director slapped in the middle), but this is a trivial example for illustration.